Need to convert Keras model to TensorFlow.js but facing version compatibility issues between TensorFlow and Keras
When I tried to convert a .h5 model by using this command in the terminal
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras model.h5 ./folder

I got an output that says "ValueError: Expected Keras version 2; got Keras version 3.3.3".
So, I reinstalled keras for keras 2.6.0, but THAT didn't work because tensorflow 2.16.1 requires  keras to be at least version 3.0.0. So, the logical thing I tried to do was to downgrade tensorflow  to a version that is compatible to keras 2.6.0, but there isn't a version of tensorflow that I can choose to install that actually is. There's only two versions of tensorflow that I can choose from: tensorflow 2.16.0rc and tensorflow 2.16.1, and neither are compatible with keras 2.6.0. I'm kind of new to all of this, so if my problem seems trivial, don't overthink it.

What's your python version?

@Lescurel Python 3.12.3

You need to downgrade your python version to install TensorFlow < 2.16
As of today (2024-06-10), TensorFlow versions < 2.16 are not compatible with Python 3.12. Refer to this table: Tested build configuration to check compatibility.
You can also check the tensorflow package on PyPi. For example, the version 2.15.1 has binary packages available for Python 3.9 to 3.11.
